# how to print char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

how can i print a char array such i initialize and then concatenate to another char array? Please see code below

```
int main () {
char dest[1020];
char source[7]="baby";
cout <<"source: " <<source <<endl;
cout <<"return value: "<<strcat(dest, source) <<endl;
cout << "pointer pass: "<<dest <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

this is the output

```
source: baby
return value: v����baby
pointer pass: v����baby
```

basically i would like to see the output print

```
source: baby
return value: baby
pointer pass: baby
```

Comment: Try zeroing out your `dest` array first.  `char dest[1020] = {0};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't initialized `dest`

```
char dest[1020] = ""; //should fix it
```

You were just lucky that it so happened that the 6th (random) value in `dest` was `0`. If it was the 1000th character, your return value would be much longer. If it were greater than 1024 then you'd get undefined behavior.

Strings as `char` arrays must be delimited with `0`. Otherwise there's no telling where they end. You could alternatively say that the string ends at its zeroth character by explicitly setting it to 0;

```
char dest[1020];
dest[0] = 0;
```

Or you could initialize your whole array with 0's

```
char dest[1024] = {};
```

And since your question is tagged `C++` I cannot but note that in C++ we use `std::string`s which save you from a lot of headache. Operator + can be used to concatenate two `std::string`s

Comment: It's undefined behavior, period.

Comment: what is the difference by initializing `char dest[1020] = "";` or `char dest[1020] = {0};` as pointed by linuxuser27 above

Comment: @James: Technically, yes, but practically, on **all** implementations I know of, if it so happened that one of the characters were zero, nothing worse than wrong results would happen. But in any case, I agree that it's UB anyway

Comment: @user945511: both `char dest[1020] = {0}` and `char dest[1020] = {};` set ALL characters to 0. `char dest[1020] = ""` sets just the first.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: `char dest[1020]=""` would also set all characters to 0 according to the new standard that just came out, though not clearly stated in the previous standard in 2003.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Accessing uninitialized memory is undefined behavior, precisely because you can't know what is in it (and something in it might cause problems).  In this case, _if_ the memory contains a `'\0'` at least five characters before the end, the effect of the undefined behavior will probably not crash the program, but that doesn't make it defined.  (You're describing a typical behavior, in the face of undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `char[]`.  If you write:

```
std::string dest;
std::string source( "baby" )
//  ...
dest += source;
```

, you'll have no problems.  (In fact, your problem is due to the fact
that `strcat` requires a `'\0'` terminated string as its first argument,
and you're giving it random data.  Which is undefined behavior.)

Comment: You can use char[], but then you need to tag the question as C, not as C++ ;)

Comment: i cannot use std::string because im dealing with characters

Comment: @user945511: Huh? You can index a string with `[]` just like `char[]`

Comment: @TristramGräbener You can use `char[]` in C++ too.  It just makes your life a lot harder.  I'd consider it something reserved for the experts, working in low-level close to the hardware code.

Comment: @JamesKanze it was just a joke. Of course you can. And in some extremely weird situations it might even be better.

Answer (score 1):

your `dest` array isn't initialized. so `strcat` tries to append `source` to the end of `dest` wich is determined by a trailing `'\0'` character, but it's undefined where an uninitialized array might end... (if it does at all...)

so you end up printing more or less random characters until accidentially a `'\0'` character occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char dest[1020];
    memset (dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    char source[7] = "baby";
    cout << "Source: " << source << endl;
    cout << "return value: " << strcat_s(dest, source) << endl;
    cout << "pointer pass: " << dest << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Did using VS 2010 Express.
clear memory using [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) as soon as you declare dest, it's more secure. Also if you are using VC++, use strcat_s() instead of strcat().

Comment: Clearing memory with `memset` is more secure than initializing with  `= {};` ? oO